# Is there a less verbose mode to generating a set of numbers in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I often need to generate a range of IDs using a sequential number.

I use code like this ...

```sql
SELECT 
    numbers.value
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            (((c3.d * 10) + c2.d) * 10) + c1.d value
        FROM
            (SELECT 0 d UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) c1,
            (SELECT 0 d UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) c2,
            (SELECT 0 d UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) c3
    ) numbers
WHERE
    numbers.value BETWEEN 192 AND 264
```

This is then used in the context required.

Is there a less verbose way to do this?

If I was on MSSQL, then a CTE would be ideal. A function is also a possibility, but not exactly sure how to achieve that.

EDIT: I'm using mysql 5, so no `WITH` unfortunately.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75785/how-to-generate-a-sequence-in-mysql/204513

Comment: MySQL 5.x or 8.x?